# What is these factor multiplying the current of the copper wires_?

Tags: transformer, analysis, electric-machine

I was reading some solved problems about transformers but I don’t understand how was calculated the losses in the copper.

**- Enunciate**:
A one phase, 10kVA, 2400/240, 60Hz distribution transformer has the following characteristics:
 - Core loss at full voltage=100W
 - Copper loss at half load=60W
Determine the efficiency of the transformer when it  delivers full load at 0.8
power factor lagging.

- **Solution**:
  P=10*0.8=8kW

Pcore=100W

PCU,FL (Full load)=60(\$**2^2**)=240W\$

The Efficiency is then
(8000/(8000+100+240))*100=95.92%

Not a big deal, but why the copper loss at half load was multyplied by \$2^2\$? What is this?

Comment: Because the copper loss was specified at half load. Full load = 2* the current = 2**2 power.

Comment: Because copper losses are from a constant resistance, full load means two times the current, and the power over a resistor is P=I²*R.

Comment: Ok, I got the idea